# I can't get the Union of two arrayLists

Tags: java

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> union
        (ArrayList<E>array1, ArrayList<E>array2)
{
  //arrayUnion will be the arrayList that will be returned
  ArrayList <E> arrayUnion  = new ArrayList <E>(array1);   
  arrayUnion.addAll(array2);
  E current;

  for(int i = 0; i < arrayUnion.size(); i++)
  {
      for(int j = 0; j < arrayUnion.size(); j++)
      {
          current = arrayUnion.get(i);
          if(current.equals(arrayUnion.get(j)))
          {
              arrayUnion.remove(j);
          }
      }
  }

      return arrayUnion;
}
```

For my test of this method, this was the output:

> The first list is [ww, ee, rr, t, yy]
>
> The second list is [ww, ss, ee, dd]
>
> The union of both ArrayLists is: [ee, t, ww, dd]

What went wrong..? I've been stuck on this for far too long and I never want to hear the word Union again. Plz help

Comment: You can't just do a `Set<E> s = new HashSet<E>; s.addAll(array1); s.addAll(array2);`?

Comment: can you try starting the second for loop with int j=i+1;

Comment: My personal approach to this would be to iterate through both array lists and *add* any equalities to the `arrayUnion` list.

Comment: @Vulcan, union is a set operation which means the list should have only unique elements.. However it's kind of weird to do a union of two arraylists since array lists are not sets (since they can have duplicates)

Comment: @MattWolfe Oops, I honestly don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has to do check the current item is checked with itself. If not you have to remove the item and decrease the `j` with one as you have to check again the item replaced at `j`. I have modified your code to work for your case. Just look at the condition check for item to be removed.

```
public static <E> ArrayList< E > union( ArrayList< E > array1, ArrayList< E > array2 ) {
    // arrayUnion will be the arrayList that will be returned
    ArrayList< E > arrayUnion = new ArrayList< E >( array1 );
    arrayUnion.addAll( array2 );
    E current;

    for ( int i = 0; i < arrayUnion.size( ); i++ ) {

        for ( int j = 0; j < arrayUnion.size( ); j++ ) {
            current = arrayUnion.get( i );

            if ( i != j && current.equals( arrayUnion.get( j ) ) ) {
                arrayUnion.remove( j );
                --j;// This is set to check the item which replace the removed item at previous statement
            }
        }
    }

    return arrayUnion;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Set` to get the union, which handles it much better. The only think you should notice is it might change the order of the elements.

Here is an example:

```
    List<String> setA = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> setB = new ArrayList<String>();

    setA.add("aa");
    setA.add("bb");
    setA.add("cc");

    setB.add("dd");
    setB.add("ee");
    setB.add("ff");

    Set<String> union = new HashSet<String>();
    union.addAll(setA);
    union.addAll(setB);

    System.out.println(setA);
    System.out.println(setB);
    System.out.println(union);
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove the very first element (or any element for i=j) immediately since it is equal to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you are doing this.  Add all elements of `array1` to the `arrayUnion`. Then iterate over it and for each item check whether it is in the `array2` (using `array2.contains(<E>))`. If it is not there remove it and you will end up with the union :-)

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> union(ArrayList<E> array1,
        ArrayList<E> array2) {
    // arrayUnion will be the arrayList that will be returned
    ArrayList<E> arrayUnion = new ArrayList<E>(array1);
    // arrayUnion.addAll(array2);
    E current;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayUnion.size(); i++) {       
            current = arrayUnion.get(i);
            if(!array2.contains(current)){
                arrayUnion.remove(current);
            }
    }

    return arrayUnion;
}
```